# Is this Proof Correct? (Order of a Jordan Block without Leading Diagonal)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, jordan-normal-form

I am wanting to prove that the smallest positive integer $p$ such that
$(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^p = 0_{r\times r}$ is $r$, where $J_r(\lambda)$ is the Jordan Block of size $r\times r$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I think I have a proof by induction but it seems so silly/easy that it *can't* be right?!

> Induction Start: Consider
>   $(J_2(\lambda) - \lambda I_2) =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
>   Sure enough, the
>   smallest positive integer $p$ such that 
>   $(J_2(\lambda) - \lambda I_2)^p = 0_{2\times 2}$ is $2$.
>
> Induction Step: Suppose that the smallest integer $k > 2$ such that
>   $(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^k = 0_{r\times r}$ is $r$ (for $r > 2$).
>
> Then 
>   $(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^{k+1} = $
>   $(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^k (J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r) = $
>   $0_{r\times r} (J_r(\lambda) -\lambda I_r) = 0_{r\times r}$. 
>   Then the smallest positive integer $k+1$ such that
>   $(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^{k+1} = 0_{r \times r}$ is $r$.

Is there something wrong with this? Or is it good to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is incorrect. First of all, your induction structure would require you to prove something about powers of $(J_{r+1}(\lambda) - \lambda I_{r+1})$, which you haven't even written down. Second, when you write
$$
(J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r)^{k+1} = (J_2(\lambda) - \lambda I_2)^k (J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r),
$$
this is quite mistaken: even besides changing $r$ to $2$ without justification, the right-hand side is the product of a $2\times 2$ matrix with an $r\times r$ matrix, which is undefined in general. Indeed, for this last reason (the statement you want to prove for many $r$ involves matrices that don't play well with one another), induction seems like it would be very hard to carry out.

Suggestion: experiment with calculating the actual powers when $r=3$ and $r=4$. Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: Thanks! It seems I was just using induction on $p$ which makes no sense. I should have at least used induction on $r$ but as you pointed out, even this would be a bad approach. Also just to note, I accidentally copied the $2$s from the previous step in the induction step. They were meant to be $r$s. I have fixed this up.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted by Greg Martin, your approach doesn't work. One approach that will is to consider the transformational properties of $A = J_r(\lambda) - \lambda I_r$. Remember the $i$th column of $A$ is $Ae_i$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th $r\times 1$ standard basis vector. Thus $Ae_1 = \vec{0}$ and $Ae_i = e_{i-1}$. From there you can determine the action of $A^k$ on the standard basis and this will give you the desired result.